# How to divide the WPF MahApps.MetroWindow Titlebar in two different sections with different colors?

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, mahapps.metro, titlebar

I would like to divide my `MahApps.MetroWindow` Titlebar into two different sections (with different colors). Or at least be able to set a template for the `MahApps.MetroWindow` Titlebar to set a custom layout which divides it.

How it is:
[One titlebar with a solid color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEDQP.png)

How it should be:
[One titlbar with two sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy7Vj.png)

I tried to edit the `MahApps.MetroWindow` Theme XAML File but it was too complex to edit something in without breaking it.
Here the file: [MahApps.MetroWindow Theme](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/Themes/MetroWindow.xaml)

Answer (score 1):

Without editing the `MahApps.MetroWindow` theme, here is how to set the `WindowTitleBrush` property creating a two colors Brush:

```
<mahapps:MetroWindow
    x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mahapps="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    Title="Test Window" Height="450" Width="800">

    <mahapps:MetroWindow.WindowTitleBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.2" />
            <GradientStop Color="CornflowerBlue" Offset="0.2" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </mahapps:MetroWindow.WindowTitleBrush>
...
...
...
```